# cant do for loop in tkinter - python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a code that I manualy inserted to the code some of my games and wanted to randomize one of them to choose and play, lately I thought of a way to automate the games it takes instead of me each time manually adding a game/
with os I tried to go to a specific directory and get the name of directories from there but when I put the list of it in a for loop it cant work, here is the code:

```
games = []
def game(vname, gname):
        if vname.get() == 1:
            games.append(gname)
        else:
            games.remove(gname)
    count=0
    question=tkinter.Label(root, text="what games do you want to play?")
    question.pack()
    steamgames = next(os.walk('C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common'))[1]
    numberofgames = len(steamgames)
    tries = 0
    strings = {}
    stringsVar = {}
    for i in range (0, numberofgames):
        this = steamgames[i]
        stringsVar[i] = tkinter.IntVar()
        strings[i] = tkinter.Checkbutton(root, text=this, variable=stringsVar[i], command=lambda: game(stringsVar[i], this))
        strings[i].pack()
        tries = tries + 1
```

Because of the loop it can't check if the box is checked or not.

Edit: the problem is that when the tkinter runs it constently checks if the box is 0 or 1 which means if it's checked or unchecked, when i put a tkinter box in the for loop it returns error that it can't check if the box is checked or unchecked, because the name of the variable is only the last variable that was in the loop and the rest are forgotten in the loop.

Comment: There is not enough context shown to give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: i edited the comment if it helps